# How to emulate back() method for array?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, boost-ublas

There is no back() method in boost::numeric::ublas::vector,
is it possible to emulate it in user code with preprocessor macro defining somehow `array_name[array_name.size()-1]`?

`array_name[i].rbegin()->operator[] (i) = 1.0` or 
`array_name[i][array_name[i].size()-1][i] = 1.0` hard to read, `array_name[i].back()[i] = 1.0` easy to read, that why i thinking to emulate back() method.

Comment: Why don't you use the `end` iterator?

Comment: Why on Earth would you use a macro for this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C-arrays. Then you'll have `array_name.back()` as well. Note, that `std::array<>` comes with no overhead to C-arrays.

If it really has to be C-arrays with static size, then

```
array_name[(sizeof(array_name) / sizeof(array_name[0])) - 1]
```

should do the trick, though I have not yet tested. Dynamically sized arrays (those allocated with `new` or `malloc()`) don't carry any length information. You can not determine their last element, without having stored the length somewhere else.

BTW.: `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` does have `size()`, so you can do

```
vector_name[vector_name.size() - 1]
```

It also has reverse iterators. You can do

```
*(vector_name.rbegin())
```

to get the value of the last element.

Comment: Question in not actually about how to access last element, it is about how to do that with trim syntax

Comment: @morte How about creating a free standing function and fill it with the suggestion of this answer? (don't use a macro for this)

Comment: @morte is `*(vector_name.rbegin())` or `array_name.back()` still too complicated?

Comment: @cdonat Yes, imagine accessing last elements in 3D-vector, there is no back() method.

Comment: @morte what is the last element of a 3D-Vector? I guess it is the third one, so it is `vector_name[2]`. If you are writing generic code, that does not know the dimensions of the vector it works with, then `*(vector_name.rbegin())`, or `vector_name[vector_name.size() - 1]` should give you, what you need. To be more generic, you can of course overload a function, e.g. `last_element(std::array<T>)` and `last_element(boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T>)`. Then your generic code call `last_element()` and based on the type of vector/array/etc. you have, it will call the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a free standing function which supplies the syntactic sugar you are asking for:

```
template <typename C>
typename C::const_reference back(const C & container)
{
    return *container.rbegin();
}
```

This will work for all classes with a `rbegin()` method and `const_reference` nested type. Add a second overload for non-const references if needed.

See this [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c51b79f19075f622)